# Can you get realtime data from an Apple Watch workout?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2, watchos

Is there a possibility in watchOS 1 or watchOS 2 where you can get real-time data of the built-in Workout app, or would I need to create my own workout app to do so?

In case I made my own app, would I still be able to store the workout in the Activity app, as the built-in one does?

Comment: @casillas - It does not give me an answer to my question :)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old question but nevertheless...

You would need to create your own WatchKit app to start the workout and to send messages from the Watches HealthKit database.

You would have to create a StreamingQuery on the Watch and send messages to the companion app on the iPhone with data.

Alternately you could simply query the iPhone HealthKit database but there might be a big timely while the data sync's from the Watch to the phone.

And yes you would be able to create and store your own Workouts in HealthKit

Comment: Thanks Duncan - nice of you to reply, eventhough its an old question. :)